# Set the default time zone for the PHP application

Tags: php, date, timezone, set, default

I am wondering if we can also use the `init_set()` function to set the default time.

- a- I know that that we can set the timezone zone in editing the php.ini.
- b- Using the Linux time() command on PHP.
- c- `init_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Edinburgh');`

The reason that I asked it was one other questions that I come across in a book. And the answer is only A.

Is the book wrong?

It should be A and C right?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. You have been more than helpful in answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also option D: use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). The function you refer to in C is actually [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). So the three ways are:

1. add a line in php.ini:

   `date.timezone = "Europe/Edinburgh"`
2. use ini_set:

   `ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Edinburgh');`
3. use date_default_timezone_set:

   `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Edinburgh');`

The thing to note about options 2&3 is that they have to be called every time you run a script. So if you need to change the timezone for every script you run, it is easier to use option 1 (assuming you have edit access to php.ini).

As for option B, I guess in theory it could work but do you really want to play with your system's time? (hint: no).

Answer (score 0):

The point of this question is not about init_set() itself, but rather the value specified. Check for available timezone from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php). It will emit E_WARNING **Invalid date.timezone value 'Europe/Edinburgh'**